# How to change the indentation width in emacs javascript mode

Tags: javascript, emacs, indentation

I'd like to use 2 spaces for my indents instead of 4. I can change the default behavior of C mode using:

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

How do I change this in javascript mode?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`js-indent-level` can be used in the default javascript-mode, which is included by default starting in emacs 23.2.

```
(setq js-indent-level 2)
```

should do what you're looking for. If you're using an older version of emacs, you may be in java-mode.  I think this mode responds to `c-basic-offset`, however I may be wrong.

Comment: (setq default-tab-width 2) would be the corresponding tab width setter for java-mode

Comment: Using this mechanism the tab width remains at 8 and so tabs are only used if indent level is 4 (2x4=8) or more. How do you set tab width to 2 or 4 so that tabs instead of spaces are used? I've tried a bunch of settings, e.g. (setq tab-width 4) but to no avail. My goal: use tab width 4, and only use tab characters (not spaces as a substitute).

Comment: jdp: Try `(defun my-javascript-mode-hook () (setq indent-tabs-mode t tab-width 4 js-indent-level 4)) (add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook 'my-javascript-mode-hook)`.

Comment: Use `js-mode-hook`, like so: `(defun my-js-mode-hook () (setq indent-tabs-mode t tab-width 4 js-indent-level 4)) (add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-js-mode-hook)`

Comment: Does the value for `js-indent-level` inherit from anywhere? Can I change a single variable like "`global-indent-level`" to change the behavior of all the languages I work with?

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? Was there a way of finding this information without stackoverflow? I looked in `M-x h` from js-mode, but couldn't find anything there.

Comment: Seems like Javascript mode does not honor `c-basic-offset`. When I put `// -*- js-indent-level: 2 -*-` at the top of my file, it works, but when I use `c-basic-offset` it does not, in Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: I'm on emacs26 and js2-mode, but that solution still works!

Comment: This works also: `M-x customize-option` and at prompt `Customize variable:` type  `js-indent-level`.

Answer (score 91):

I wish someone had told me about Custom a lot sooner!  Perhaps this will help another mere mortal like me ;)

Invoke Custom:

```
M-x customize
```

Then, choose "Programming," and then "Languages," and then select a language/mode to customize.  Edit the options as you see fit.  When done, choose either "Save for current session" or "Save for future sessions."

Answer (score 17):

If you're using js2-mode (which is more powerful IMHO), then the command is:

```
(setq-default js2-basic-offset 2)
```

[Source.](https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/js2-mode-setup-recommendation/)

Answer (score 12):

You might also want to set emacs to use spaces instead of tabs

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Comment: This is more a comment then actual answer. Earn more reputation to be able to comment.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
M-x customize-variable
```

and type

```
js-indent-level
```

(`js-` [TAB] shows a list of options). Then change the `Js Indent Level` as wanted and click `[State:]` and save.

Comment: An alternative approach might be using `M-x describe-variable` + click on "customize".

Answer (score 2):

In my javascript.el file (/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp) I found

javascript-indent-level 4

So if you  are using the same lisp-mode you can change it by running

```
(setq javascript-indent-level 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) could be a good idea too. And of course, Emacs had a mode for it [editorconfig-emacs](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs).

It's also available in the package manager (`M-x package-list-packages`) through Melpa or Marmalade.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change it on a per-file basis, put this at the top of your file:

```
// -*- mode: js; js-indent-level: 2; -*-
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me after upgrading to Emacs 26 (I already had `js-indent-level` set to 2 but my tab width went back to 8), but what did work was setting the `tab-width` variable to `2`, which seems to replace the old `default-tab-width` variable.

I found this in `M-x customize` by searching for `tab width`.