# How can I set a tab width for JSON files?

Tags: json, emacs, indentation

I have the following in my `.emacs` file.  But it doesn't change the tab width in `.json` files.

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq standard-indent 2)
```

I'm using emacs 24.3 on OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 51):

```
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'js-indent-level)
            (setq tab-width 2)
            (setq js-indent-level 2)))
```

Make the variable buffer local so that it does not conflict with `js-mode` for JavaScript files.

Comment: It works well with `js2-mode`. [Js2Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Js2Mode)

Answer (score 6):

I used `M-x customize` as mentioned here: [How to change the indentation width in emacs javascript mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177929/how-to-change-the-indentation-width-in-emacs-javascript-mode)

It inserted `'(js-indent-level 2)` into my .emacs file.

But thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 5):

it's better to set tab width in the corresponding hook - find the name of major mode (for example, by using the `M-: major-mode`, and then define the hook where to set the value:

```
(defun my/json-mode-hook ()
   (setq tab-width 4))
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'my/js2-mode-hook)
```